# Where can I find an extremely slim wooden stirring spoon?

Tags: cookware, utensils, mixing

A friend of mine has this very slim wooden stirring spoon. It's handle is a little thicker than a pencil, and the spoon itself is about 1.5 inches wide.

It does any amazing job of stirring and mixing.

I asked my friend but she doesn't remember where she got it. I've been looking everywhere for something similar with no such luck.

Comment: Providing a picture could be helpful here.

Comment: It is possible that it's a [muddling spoon](https://www.google.com/search?q=muddling+spoon&safe=active&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDq4ei7LLRAhVB7oMKHYtOBKgQ7AkIVg&biw=1304&bih=678#imgrc=c_WhaRbWFgTTTM%3A)?

Comment: If you happen to be in indonesia sometime, try looking around at a market. I recall there being a great number of elegantly made wooden and coconut-shell spoons.

Comment: The only one that I have is probably 30+ years old.  (my mom was going to get rid of it, I grabbed it)

Answer (score 2):

We've got one or two that shape (perhaps with a slightly thicker handle but ergonomically that suits me). Without any particular reason to buy them, and knowing that they're quite light and very similar to some others we have I can be fairly confident that they came in a multi pack of cheap spoons. Maybe everywhere you've looked is too up-market

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what you mean.  I've been on a similar quest myself.  Finding a wooden spoon with a slim handle is not easy. Most of the "premium" spoons on the market have very thick handles, which I don't find comfortable or aesthetically pleasing.

I've had good luck with Etsy.  Most of the products are handmade, so you could probably work out something with the seller to make the handle a specific thickness.

Here are a couple that I thought looked nice and match your description:

https://www.etsy.com/listing/223564309/handmade-walnut-spoon-cooking-spoon
https://www.etsy.com/listing/229429832/hand-carved-walnut-wood-spoon

Good luck!  Glad to know I'm not the only person who prefers slim wooden spoons.

Comment: Yeah, i'm quite particular about my cooking utensils.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but might you be interested in a bartender spoon / bar spoon? Google it and click image results. It fits your description I believe. 
Hope this helps :)